# laravel 5.4 incrementing page hits with event and listeners

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models with many to many relationship artists and songs.

then there are fields in my artists table called weekhits and week_date,
i want to increment the value of week-hits when ever a specific artist page is visited by the user

so made event listners

```
class ArtistEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $artist;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(artist $artist)
    {
        //
        $this->artist = $artist;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

ant this is the listener

```
class ArtistViewed
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ArtistEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ArtistEvent $event)
    {
        $event->artist->increment('week_hits');
    }
}
```

and here is where i fired the listener.

```
public function artist($id,$slug){
        $artist = Artist::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        Event::fire(new ArtistViewed($artist));

        return view('front.artist', compact('artist'));
    }
```

but this code isnot incrementing week-hits field in my artists table..

plz help. iam in the middle of learning laravel.

Comment: `$event->artist()->increment('week_hits');` ?  artist is a function and im not shure but you dont have to call the save function after increment?

Comment: it is not method. it is an instance of artist

Comment: Can you dd($event->artist) in your handle() function... what does it give, does it get there?

Comment: even when i dd it isnot dying dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already added an answer that suggests using a job for this, but if you want to go with the existing event/listener setup then just fix the call to `Event::fire()` to actually fire your event, not your listener.

```
Event::fire(new ArtistEvent($artist))
```

Also ensure that the event and listener are registered in your `EventServiceProvider`'s `$listen` array.

```
\App\Events\ArtistEvent::class => [
    \App\Listeners\ArtistViewed::class
]
```

Comment: this solved my problem. that is what i wanted, to increment week_hits field in my artists table when ever an artist page is visited or reloaded the page to increment that field,  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing events and listeners - you're firing off the listener to `Event::fire()` and you pass the `$artist` into the constructor of the listener, but instead try and take it off the `$event`.

Keep in mind if your queue driver isn't `sync` then you will actually need to run your queue from the command line, otherwise these jobs will never be run.

Below is an example of how you might do this with a job that you dispatch. You could fire this off by calling `dispatch(new RecordArtistView($artist))`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Artist;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RecordArtistView extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $artist;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  \App\Artist  $artist
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Artist $artist)
    {
        $this->artist = $artist;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->artist->increment('week_hits');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it be done using `Job` instead of `Event` ? I think job will make it more complicated and might add latency while events like page view should update instantaneously.

Comment: Ah, normally an event listener would be queued - assumed you were doing that here. A reason you might queue this is because you're actually adding latency to the page load (it would need to update the artist on every request) when it could be done later.

Comment: If you want to go with the event/listener setup have then change `Event::fire` to actually fire the event, not the listener.

Comment: So are event listener queue handled same way as job queue ? if I have queue driver as `database` , will I see event listener queue also in database ?

Comment: Sorry, event listeners aren't queued by default - you would have to opt-in to that. If you aren't queuing your event listeners then it should happen as part of the same request. Check out my other answer.